# Code Refactor. Instead of using foreach on a list use lambda expressions

Tags: c#, lambda

I'm thinking if these line of codes can be simplified using lambda expressions like using `valueList.ForEach`? I'm new on lambda expressions.

```
foreach (var item in OrderList)
{
    item.ReserveDate = DateTime.ParseExact(item.ReserveDate, "yyyyMMdd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToShortDateString();
    item.ExpireDate = DateTime.ParseExact(item.ExpireDate, "yyyyMMdd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToShortDateString();
}
```

Comment: Far from simplifying it, I think trying to use lambdas here will just make it more complicated. This code is absolutely fine as it is.

Comment: The results would be less efficient than the method you are using.  The left side of the results would have to be a new variable since you can't have the same variable on both side of a lambda expression.  Then you would have to take the new variable and assign it back to the OrderList.

Comment: One thing a lambda could improve here is create a more `DRY` approach: `Func<string,sting> parse = d => DateTime.ParseExact(d, "yyyyMMdd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToShortDateString();` (created before the loop) and use the lambda to assign both values `item.ReserveDate = parse(item.ReserveDate);`

Comment: @MatthewWatson Is it adviseable to use automapper just for this kind of problem?

Comment: @DerpukuDer Well, there's quite a bit of debate about whether one should use Automapper. Personally I wouldn't for this simple case.

Answer (score 1):

You can write like this, but I don't know if it's actually more readable than foreach:

```
OrderList.ForEach(item => {
    item.ReserveDate = DateTime.ParseExact(item.ReserveDate, "yyyyMMdd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToShortDateString();
    item.ExpireDate = DateTime.ParseExact(item.ExpireDate, "yyyyMMdd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToShortDateString();
});
```

Unless you can use work on those in parallel (but again, readability):

```
Parallel.ForEach(OrderList, item => {
    item.ReserveDate = DateTime.ParseExact(item.ReserveDate, "yyyyMMdd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToShortDateString();
    item.ExpireDate = DateTime.ParseExact(item.ExpireDate, "yyyyMMdd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToShortDateString();
});
```

Comment: I think this shows what I meant by my comment to the OP. ;)

Comment: @Matthew Is it adviseable to use automapper just for this kind of problem?